# Importar, ler e converter dados cruzados para um data.frame

Tags: r

Tenho uma tabela que não esta no formato de leitura padrão do R, ou seja, ela tem uma variável em coluna (tempo) e duas em linha com os dados dispostos lado a lado (sujeito e tratamento). Alguém conseguiria me dar uma luz de como fazer com que o R consiga importar, ler e converter estes dados que estão cruzados para um data frame?

[image: Concentrações plasmáticas individuais]

Comment: Weidson, por favor poste uma amostra dos seus dados como arquivo, texto selecionável ou objeto do R, porque desta forma não temos como ler os seus dados sem criá-los manualmente.

Comment: Sobre o problema em si, eu resolveria no excel. Basta criar uma nova linha e usar a função `CONCATENAR` nas linhas 2 e 3 para criar o nome das colunas, e depois disso você pode apagar as três primeiras linhas ou usar o argumento `skip`.

Comment: Pessoal, muito obrigado pela ajuda e por favor vai desculpando a falta de experiência com o R e com o fórum (aos poucos eu vou aprendendo mais). Quando postei esta pergunta eu não sabia se quer as premissas básicas de leitura do R. Ou seja, tive que me familiarizar mais com a linguagem para achar a solução com a ajuda de um colega deste fórum.  Para que possamos fazer o R entender a conexão entre dados e variáveis não podemos ter mescladas como ilustrado acima (desta forma fica praticamente inviável formar variáveis).

Comment: Com o tempo descobri as premissas básicas de que para fazer a manipulação é necessário ter sempre variáveis dispostas em colunas. Portanto, o que eu precisava saber era simplesmente como formar variáveis. Segue o link do que eu realmente pretendia fazer.[link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164309/concatenar-valores-dentro-de-uma-mesma-colunas-do-data-frame-no-r-software)

Answer (score 1):

Ler não é problema, pode usar read.table com o parâmetro skip =2, para pular as 2 primeiras linhas, e ler os dados de um arquivo csv. Depois pode usar reshape do reshape2 para colocar banco em formato long.

Comment: Ok...entendi a dica. Mas como eu poderia automatizar a mudança de nome? Eu teria 500 sujeitos para mudar manualmente o nome? Seria possível fazer a automação da mudança do nome?

Comment: Ok...entendi a dica. Mas como eu conseguiria colocar as informação do tratamento? Por favor perceba que hora o sujeito toma o tratamento A no primeiro período e B no segundo e hora ele toma o tratamento B no primeiro período e A no segundo. Preciso indexar estas informações no data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Prezado @WeidsonC.deSouza, você poderia melhorar suas perguntas? Coloque um pedaço maior da planilha e explique melhor o que deseja! Em relação a ler o banco de dados e importar para o R você pode usar o código:

```
library(readr)
df <- read_delim("local_do_arquivo",";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE,skip = 2)
```