# Concatenar valores dentro de uma mesma colunas do data frame no R software

Tags: r

f[image: Dados de Concentração plasmática]

Alguém poderia me ajudar? De qualquer forma ja estou grato!!!

Answer (score 2):

Pesquise a ajuda fa função `paste`. Se o seu data frame é `df` pode fazer:

```
re1<- apply(df[1:3,-1],2,paste,collapse="_")
nomes<- c(df[3,1],re1)
```

Novo df:

```
df1 <- df[-c(1:3),]
colnames(df1)<- nomes
```

Comment: Eu apliquei sua sugestão mas ele não incluiu a variável V1. Ou seja, ele só concatenou as variáveis V2, V3, V4, V5. Além do que eu também preciso que estas células concatenadas permaneça dentro do data frame. Quando eu pedi para imprimir o data frame os resultados estavam como antes da concaternação.

Comment: Essa é outra questão. Vc esta querendo excluir as 2 primeiras linhas e substituir os nomes das colunas em um novo data frame! Como não postou um exemplo reproduzível veja uma sugestão na resposta atualizada.

Comment: Você adivinhou Robert!!! Em um segundo momento eu iria pedir para trocar o resultado da concaternação pelo resultado de V1, V2, V3, V4 e V5. Agora por outro lado, quando reproduzi este seu último código verifiquei que quando imprimo df1 no lugar da variável "Time" (no cabeçalho) aparece o número "16". Preciso que apareça "Time".   O que esta acontecendo?

Comment: O que pode ser alterado neste código que você forneceu acima para aparecer o nome "Time" no cabeçalho ao invés do número "16"? Muito obrigado pela excelente ajuda!!!

Answer (score -2):

Pronto já descobri....

O correto seria:

```
N_row_concatenate<-3 # Digite ao lado o número de   linhas que você deseja 
                     #concaternar para formar o nome da nova variável!!!

Head_Name <-apply(Df[1:N_row_concatenate,-(1+ncol(Df))],2,paste,collapse="_")
New_Df <- Df[-c(1:N_row_concatenate),]
colnames(New_Df)<- Head_Name
New_Df_long <- melt(New_Df, id=c(Head_Name[1:1]))
```

De qualquer forma muito obrigado pela ideia inicial. Ela foi de grande valia!